# If $X$ is a discrete random variable, then $\mathcal{X}$, the range of $X$, is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

$F_{X}$ denotes the CDF of a random variable $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$ ($S$ the sample space). I'm not caring about the $\sigma$-algebra technicalities for now.

My definition of a discrete random variable $X$ is the following:

> If $F_{X}$ is a step function, $X$ is said to be **discrete**. That
>   is, $X$ is discrete if and only if \begin{equation*} F_{X}(x) =
>  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}\mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x) \end{equation*} for all $x
>  \in \mathbb{R}$, where $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$ are intervals that
>   partition $\mathbb{R}$.

From this definition, is it possible to show that $\mathcal{X}$, the range of $X$, is countable? If so, I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Only "almost surely". What is $p(\{s : X(s) \in (a,b)\})$?

Comment: That's really not the usual definition of "discrete". By _that_ definition the range of a discrete random variable is actually _finite_!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Should the partition be infinite? Casella and Berger doesn't say anything other than "$F_{X}$ is a step function," so I had to make a guess as to what the partition should be.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Of course, they didn't bother defining what a step function should be other than that it "has jumps"

Comment: @DanielFischer That would be $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}F_{X}(x)-F_{X}(a)$, right? (or something like that)

Comment: The usual definition of "discrete random variable" is "random variable that takes only countably many values". Which would make your problem sort of easy. Whether that definition is the same as "the CDF is a step function" depends on the unspecified definition of "step function". For example, say $q_1,\dots$ are the rationals, $a_j\ge0$ and $\sum a_j<\infty$. Say $X$ has CDF $F=\sum a_j\Bbb 1_{[q_j,\infty)}$. I wouldn't call that a "step function", but we have to in order to make their definition agree with the usual one.

Comment: See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) for the usual definition.

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes. So if $(a,b) \subset A_k$, then?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's how I learned it at first, and I know it's defined that way in a measure-theoretic treatment. I suppose this text wants to avoid that problem by merely stating it as a fact in this case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then $p(\{s: X(s) \in (a, b)\}) = \alpha_k$.

Comment: @drhab Please see [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630661/if-x-is-a-discrete-random-variable-then-mathcalx-the-range-of-x-is-c?noredirect=1#comment3325013_1630661) in particular. It may be my own misinterpretation.

Comment: @Clarinetist No, it's $0$. Point being, almost surely $X(s) \in \bigcup \partial A_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I understand. And those boundaries are countable sets, I suppose?

Comment: Well, the $A_k$ are intervals. The boundary of an interval consists of at most two points.

Comment: @DanielFischer And the union of those boundaries is at most countable... right?

Comment: If you allow only finitely many $A_k$, the union is finite. If you allow countably many intervals, the union is countable.